When uploading data with an image, if some PrimaryKeyRelatedField is missing or the field ID is not valid following issue is occurring
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
Issue:
When uploading data with an image, the following issue occurs if some PrimaryKeyRelatedField is missing or the field ID is not valid. If I don't upload any image file, then expected output field validation issues arise.
My model Looks like:
class ConsumerDetails(CreatorModifierInfo):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True, db_index=True)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    service_cost_details = models.ForeignKey(ServiceCostDetails, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='consumer/image/%Y/%m/%d/')
    citizenship_issue_district = models.ForeignKey(District, related_name='citizenship_issue_district', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    citizenship_front = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='consumer/image/%Y/%m/%d/')
    citizenship_back = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='consumer/image/%Y/%m/%d/')
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    municipality = models.ForeignKey(Municipality, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ward = models.ForeignKey(Ward, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    tol = models.ForeignKey(Tol, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_number if self.membership_number else f"{self.id}"

Serializer looks like:
class ConsumerDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    service_cost_details = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ServiceCostDetails.objects.all(), required=True, allow_empty=True, allow_null=True)
    province = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Province.objects.all(), required=True, allow_null=True, allow_empty=True)
    district = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=District.objects.all(), required=True, allow_empty=True, allow_null=True)
    municipality = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Municipality.objects.all(), required=True, allow_empty=True, allow_null=True)
    ward = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Ward.objects.all(), required=True, allow_empty=True, allow_null=True)
    tol = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tol.objects.all(), required=True, allow_empty=True, allow_null=True)
    citizenship_front = serializers.ImageField()
    citizenship_back = serializers.ImageField()
    photo = serializers.ImageField()

    Class Meta:
        model = ConsumerDetails
        fields = ['id', 'service_cost_details', 'house_number', 'old_membership_number',
                  'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'photo', 'address',
                  'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'pan_number', 'family_member_count', 'citizenship_number',
                  'citizenship_issue_district', 'citizenship_front', 'citizenship_back', 'province', 'district',
                  'municipality', 'ward', 'tol']

View looks like:
class ConsumerDetailsView(viewsets.ViewSet, CustomPagination):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, HasGroupPermission]
    def create(self, request):
        """
        Create a Consumer Detail.
        """
        serializer = ConsumerDetailsSerializer(data=request.data)
        api_status = False
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(creator=self.request.user, office=self.request.user.office)
            api_status = True
        return Response(
            {
                "status": api_status,
                "errors": serializer.errors,
                "results": serializer.data
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK if api_status else status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

Outputs:

The response from the API when every input data is correct (ie: Foreign Keys):

{
    "status": true,
    "errors": {},
    "results": {
        "id": "4cdf36aa-f026-4818-85ec-336d69457f80",
        "service_cost_details": "764fb35b-cbe9-418d-a9bc-0e55d7508dca",
        "house_number": "420",
        "old_membership_number": "",
        "first_name": "test",
        "middle_name": "test",
        "last_name": "456",
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "phone_number": "9895655644",
        "photo": "/media/consumer/image/2024/08/22/186546284_337173751174479_204832876614825673_n-11_12_13.jpg",
        "address": "madhyabindu",
        "date_of_birth": "2024-08-15",
        "gender": "Male",
        "pan_number": "420",
        "family_member_count": 4,
        "citizenship_number": "56551",
        "citizenship_issue_district": 1,
        "citizenship_front": "/media/consumer/image/2024/08/22/186474496_517472066280157_6420338440923842135_n-11_12_6.jpg",
        "citizenship_back": "/media/consumer/image/2024/08/22/186546284_337173751174479_204832876614825673_n-11_12_13_RRWIXk8.jpg",
        "province": 1,
        "district": 2,
        "municipality": 3,
        "ward": 4,
        "tol": 1
    }
}


The response from the server if I don't attach any image files and send an invalid foreign key to the server.

{
    "status": false,
    "errors": {
        "service_cost_details": ,
        "province": [
            "Invalid pk \"75242546\" - object does not exist."
        ]
    },
    "results": {
        "service_cost_details": "6230d4c0-6384-4c8e-871e-11b6987af40b",
        "house_number": "420",
        "old_membership_number": "",
        "first_name": "test",
        "middle_name": "test",
        "last_name": "456",
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "phone_number": "9895655644",
        "address": "madhyabindu",
        "date_of_birth": "2024-08-15",
        "gender": "Male",
        "pan_number": "420",
        "family_member_count": "4",
        "citizenship_number": "56551",
        "citizenship_issue_district": "1",
        "citizenship_front": null,
        "citizenship_back": null,
        "photo": null,
        "province": "75242546",
        "district": "2",
        "municipality": "3",
        "ward": "4",
        "tol": null
    }
}


If I send Invalid Foreign Key with image files, the following issue occurs. However, the expected result was a validation issue but 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte issue occurred.

[Expected Result]
{
    "status": false,
    "errors": {
        "service_cost_details": ,
        "province": [
            "Invalid pk \"75242546\" - object does not exist."
        ]
    },
    "results": {
        "service_cost_details": "6230d4c0-6384-4c8e-871e-11b6987af40b",
        "house_number": "420",
        "old_membership_number": "",
        "first_name": "test",
        "middle_name": "test",
        "last_name": "456",
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "phone_number": "9895655644",
        "address": "madhyabindu",
        "date_of_birth": "2024-08-15",
        "gender": "Male",
        "pan_number": "420",
        "family_member_count": "4",
        "citizenship_number": "56551",
        "citizenship_issue_district": "1",
        "citizenship_front": null,
        "citizenship_back": null,
        "photo": null,
        "province": "75242546",
        "district": "2",
        "municipality": "3",
        "ward": "4",
        "tol": null
    }
}

[Encountered Issue]
Encountered Issue Image: https://i.sstatic.net/pztmUD3f.png

I think this is Django Rest Framework package parser bug. I am using default parser which is parser_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES

Please [edit] your question and provide a proper [mre]. Please reduce the model / serializer code to the bare minimum needed to reproduce your issue. Don't share images of the debug page, rather click the "switch to copy-and-paste view" and share the complete error traceback.

As currently framed, this is hard to debug. Reduce the variables: (1) provide a proper province and the required service_cost_details and show us how the API responds to this request.  You want to isolate this issue you're having with the photo field.

I edited the question and added the responses from the server (ie: expected output and actual response from the server).

I think the above issue was encountered because the serializer found an invalid foreign key (FK).In the meantime, the image was being uploaded, and because of the invalid FK, the serializer raised the validation issue, and the file upload process was interrupted, resulting in the above issue. However, the expected result was a validation issue.
